# mock method calling callback function sinon

Tags: javascript, sinon

How do you mock an outer method calling a callback using sinon?
Example given the following code, getText should return 'a string' as response in the callback function

```
sinon.stub(a, 'getText').returns('a string')
let cb = function(err, response) {
   console.log(response)
}
a.getText('abc', cb)
```

and it should produce the output 'a string' since it calls callback function cb but there is no output

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`callsArgWith`](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.2.0/stubs/#stubcallsargwithindex-arg1-arg2-)

```
sinon.stub(a, 'getText').callsArgWith(1, null, 'a string')
let cb = function(err, response) {
   console.log(response); // 'a string'
}

a.getText('abc', cb)
```

Comment: thanks this works.. when i substituted 0 with 1 under callsArgWith

Comment: @Stanley Right, should be 1

Answer (score 34):

```
sinon.stub(a, 'getText').yields(null, 'a string');
```

[`yields()`](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.2.0/stubs/#stubyieldsarg1-arg2-) will call the first function argument that gets passed to the stubbed function with the arguments provided (`null, 'a string'`).

Comment: This worked like a charm. You are a savior robertklep.